# Display files uploaded to a node's body through editor in drupal 7?

Tags: nodes, files

Is there any way to display name of files uploaded to a node body through editor in drupal 7?
I know all the content in body of a node stored as text in database but want to know if there is any way to filter file uploads in body per node basis?

Comment: file upload in editor or fields?

Comment: editors @JayendraKainthola

Comment: Are you using wyswiyg editor?

Comment: @JayendraKainthola I am using ckeditor. Does it matter???

Comment: There is already imce module which allow image upload in ckeditor. You can try this module.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola Thanks for your response but my question is that : can we manage files(images or pdfs) uploaded through editor per node basis?

Comment: You mean you want to filter files from body, if I am correct?

Comment: @JayendraKainthola Now you got it.

Comment: Sorry, I have not checked if any text filter exist for the same. You can check "admin/config/content/formats/full_html" url if you found anything. Otherwise you have to create your own text filter or do some hack.